# Getting just one INT from the database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

How to fetch an integer from a mysql database using PHP and phpmyadmin.

This is my code right now:

```
session_start();
require_once("connect.php");                

$query = "SELECT klantID FROM klant ORDER BY klantID DESC LIMIT 1;";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
//echo $query."<br>"; 

while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
    echo $row['klantID']; 
    mysqli_close($conn);    
}
```

I'm trying to get the highest 'klantID' in the table 'klant'. When I run the PHP file, it shows nothing. It's just blank.

How do I debug this to find out what is wrong?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/mysqli_query  this function returns a statement HANDLE. you need to FETCH a row of results from that handle, e.g. via http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc. And note that getting nothing on your echo probably means the query failed and returned boolean false, which would print as "nothing". If the query had succeeded, you'd have seen "Resource #xx" or whatever as the output.

Comment: Copy your query and run it directly in phpMyAdmin as a query. What error do you get?

Comment: Hmm.. I have tried the fetch thingy in my code and it still shows nothing. I have edited my post, yet I still don't know what I have done wrong. When I copy my query and run it directly in phpmyadmin, I get no error: I get this http://puu.sh/f3xil/6cf298da49.png

Answer (score 1):

The PHP script returns nothing because the SQL successfully returns no rows.  You skip over the while loop and the program exits.

One way to help find out what is wrong is to read the result from `mysqli_num_rows` like this:

```
require_once("connect.php");
$sql = "SELECT `klantID` FROM `klant` ORDER BY `klantID` DESC LIMIT 1; ";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if ( mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0 )
{
    //we got a result
    $result = mysqli_fetch_object($query);
    echo "ID Found : ".$result->klantID."<br />";
 } else {
    echo "Nothing found!"
 }
```

After that fetch, the result of `mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0` evaluates to false and the program prints "Nothing found!"

Comment: Pro tip, answering posts that violate certain posting rules will probably get you downvotes:  1.  Posts that don't include an error message and are vague where: "It doesn't work tell me what to do". 2.  Posts that reveal the OP to be a total beginner, with code formatted all wrong.  3.  The question is very localized and highly specific.  it's like asking you why is there a red car out my window.  Is is there?  Was it ever there?  bad questions. Dropping birdseed on these terrible unwelcome artifacts on stackoverflow encourage more of it, which will eventually ruin the site.

Comment: albeit the post being not up to par; I still wanted to give a quick fix for the problem; I cannot comment yet! since you need 50rep; hence my post answer. but I do agree and understand your pro tip, thanks for the tip Eric

Comment: I fixed the question by doing the following things:  Fixing the 4 spelling errors.  Fixing the grammar errors.  Formatting the code to have correct tabbing and spacing.  Removed some redundant and useless comments.  generalized the question to be more along the lines of debugging and getting values from mysql with php.  Clarified his unexpected end state.  Try not to encourage helplessness in new coders by dropping mana from heaven.  You'll be up to 19k rep in no time.

Comment: Thanks Eric. The code you fixed works now! I apologize for being a complete beginner with this subject and how to use stackoverflow.